# How do I sum images?

Tags: image-stacking

I have a number of photos. I want to add these images togther pixel-wise (not mean or median). I have Imagemagick installed, and I tried:

```
composite -compose plus IMG* ~/Desktop/sum.png
```

But the output image

[image]

wasn't noticeably brighter than the input images:

[image]

Since I have 30 input images, I expected the output to be much brighter.

Why isn't this working, and how do I sum images, using either Imagemagick, or other free tool?

Comment: As @asalamon74 has pointed out, `imagemagick` will only merge *two* images in the way you've described. If you want to merge more, you can write a relatively simple bash script to take in a directory and merge all images through a series of merges. i.e. `((im1 + im2) + im3) + im4 ...`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but the free app [Star Stax](http://www.markus-enzweiler.de/software/software.html) looks like it might do some of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to asalamon74 for a solution using a bash script, which I modified to use PNG rather than JPEG, as szulat suggested.

```
convert -size 100x100 canvas:black temp.png

for f in IMG_*.jpg; do
  composite temp.png ${f} -compose Plus temp.png
done
```

I tested, and this works.

Answer (score 8):

Imagemagick cannot be used to compose 30 images in one step. The [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) states:

> Image Composition is the process of merging two (and only two) images
>   in a variety of ways.

The following simple bash script creates a black 100x100 image (temp.png) and compose all the test_*.jpg images (assuming all of them are 100x100) one by one to this image.

```
convert -size 100x100 canvas:black temp.png
for f in test_*.jpg; do
  composite temp.png "${f}" -compose Plus temp.png
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to merge 32 images in 31 steps?

Comment: yes, you can compose 32 images in 31 steps

Comment: This explains the issue, but not a solution. Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to merge images like in tournament tree? Number of opertaions will be the same but all the images will be used equally.

Comment: I think the Plus operation is associative, so tournament tree will give you the same result.

Comment: I've modified the code to use png temp image

Comment: @Crowley - This would enable parallelisation, if you had the skill to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

1. Open the 1st image.
2. Open the 2nd image as a layer (Ctrl + Alt + O).
3. Change layer mode to "Addition" (Dialogue - Layers - Mode).
4. Open next image as a layer.
5. Change layer mode to "Addition".
6. Proceed   until all images are added.

You can add all images at once (selecting them with Ctrl while opening as a layer) but you'll still have to change layer mode individually for every layer.

This procedure is also possible with any graphic editor which is capable to work with layers (Paint.net, Photoshop (not free!) etc).

Comment: Is it not possible to first import all images as layers, and then select all of them at once, right click and choose to change their mode to "Addition"? I'm not familiar with GIMP. This just doesn't seem practical for 30 images.

Comment: No, it's not possible to select multiple layers in GIMP.

Answer (score 3):

After attempting to apply the repeated `composite` technique with HDR images and ending up with clamped output, I discovered the [`-evaluate-sequence`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#evaluate-sequence) operator. Here's an example:

```
convert *.exr -evaluate-sequence Add output.exr
```

This takes all the `.exr` files (or whatever format you want) in the current directory and sums them into a new image, `output.exr`.

If that doesn't give proper HDR output you may need to ensure you have a version of image magick [built with HDR enabled](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php).